# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException

Tags: classnotfoundexception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferLimitException
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossPartGenerator.(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:193)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.read(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader.readMono(MultipartHttpMessageReader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.initMultipartData(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.createExchange(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext$ServerManager.handle(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:213)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:40)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:63)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:226)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:434)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:160)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:426)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:799)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:433)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:330)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoa**strong text**der.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
**strong text**

Comment: This error was reported in all places where files were uploaded

Comment: i hope no issues during compile time, but NoClassDefFoundError occured during runtime. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html. share your pom.xml might be dependency mismatch during runtime.